# Order entities in Core Data data model

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview

I am using Core Data in my application, and I have entities that need to be reordered. I have a collection view that is populated with NSManagedObjects from the data model, and this collection view can be reordered by dragging and dropping the cells. I want the order of the entities in the data model to reflect the order of the cells in the collection view. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I am new to Core Data, so I am still getting used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may do it simply as follows:

- add an attribute `viewOrder` to your entity, probably an integer type
- update it any time the user drags and drops a cell, i.e. re-orders the collection view (& make sure to `save:` the `NSManagedObjectContext` whenever you make any changes)
- when populating the collection view, set the `NSFetchRequest` property `sortDescriptors` to sort the results by `viewOrder`
- note that if you add new managed objects, you'll have to run a fetch to count the current number in core date or to find the max `viewOrder`